# Miktek update : SSL connect error

Tags: miktex, miktex-update

in advance
I am well aware that I am asking a question that has already been asked but I can not solve the problem and I would like a more basic description of the resolution of the problem.

I wanted to update my packages under miktex and I had the error below.

How to solve the problem?

MiKTeX Problem Report

Message: SSL connect error

Data:

Source: Libraries \ MiKTeX \ PackageManager \ CurlWebSession.cpp

Line: 348

MiKTeX: 2.9

OS: Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit, build 17134

Invokers: non-existing / explorer

SystemAdmin: yes

PowerUser: no

Root0: C: \ Users \ robert \ AppData \ Roaming \ MiKTeX \ 2.9

Root1: C: \ Users \ robert \ AppData \ Local \ MiKTeX \ 2.9

Root2: C: \ ProgramData \ MiKTeX \ 2.9

Root3: C: / localtexmf

Root4: C: \ Program Files \ MiKTeX 2.9

UserInstall: C: \ Users \ robert \ AppData \ Roaming \ MiKTeX \ 2.9

UserConfig: C: \ Users \ robert \ AppData \ Roaming \ MiKTeX \ 2.9

UserData: C: \ Users \ robert \ AppData \ Local \ MiKTeX \ 2.9

CommonInstall: C: \ Program Files \ MiKTeX 2.9

CommonConfig: C: \ ProgramData \ MiKTeX \ 2.9

CommonData: C: \ ProgramData \ MiKTeX \ 2.9

Comment: Add an issue to the miktex bug tracker.

Comment: Hello
in fact, the update works at home, the concern was probably the proxy of my institution that must filter the different access.
How do you configure the proxy on miktex?

Comment: A description for configuration miktex for proxy is missing in the documentation. Please add an bug-report on MiKTeX Homepage. As far as I remember there is an window poping up when you install MiKTeX and are behind an proxy ...